# Magento 2.2 Inventory not getting decreased when orders are created using REST API

Tags: orders, inventory, rest-api, cataloginventory

I am new to **Magento 2.2** and I want to create orders using **REST API**. Orders are getting created. But the stock value of the Product is not getting **decreased**. I have made the necessary settings in Configuration. But still, the problem persists. It is getting decreased for orders created via Admin Panel.

Thanks in advance for a favorable solution.